# Remove last comma from dynamic sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How could i remove the last comma from a part of dynamic query

```
set @Query += '[A].[ID].&[' + Convert(varchar,SUBSTRING(@string, @start, @end - @start) ) +']&[CAN],[A].[ID].&[' +Convert(varchar,SUBSTRING(@string, @start, @end - @start) ) + ']&[usa],';
```

Answer (score 4):

One common technique uses `Left` and `Len` function

```
set @Query = Left(@Query,len(@Query)-1)
```

**Update :** Run the above statement after competition of while loop/Cursor or after framing the entire query

Comment: I am using it as part of dynamic query in a loop. adding this is removing all the commas after usa.

Comment: @AshishMandal - Don't use this inside loop. Use it after framing the entire query

Answer (score 1):

Rephrase your logic and remove the first one using `stuff()`:

```
set @Query = ',[A].[ID].&[' + . . . ';
```

Then remove it as:

```
set @Query = stuff(@Query, 1, 1, '');
```